# How to write url rewrite with OR operator?

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is file structure of the site :

```
site_one_folder
index.php
```

In site_one_folder there is a file:

```
controller.php
```

I want to write rewrite rule to

1. If people search www.mysiteurl/index.php or www.mysiteurl or www.mysiteurl/, it will run index.php
2. If people search instead of index.php :
   example: I will search

`www.mysiteurl/something.php`

Then Browser will show the above url but content will have to be

```
`www.mysiteurl/site_one_folder/controller.php?para=something`
```

NB: para = searched file name excluding (.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in our root folder (where `index.php` is):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php$ /site_one_folder/controller.php?para=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: I tried this. But it does not work for index.php . For index.php it shows /site_one_folder/controller.php?para=index

Comment: @user1712287 does the index.php file exist? The two conditions ensures that any request for a file or directory that exists will be excluded.

Comment: I actually used [NC, L] . Is there any difference between L,QSA and NC,L ?

Comment: @user1712287 none of those flags will affect whether `index.php` is getting executed or not. NC=no case, QSA = query string append.

Answer (score 1):

1st condition for direct access to index.php. 2nd to avoid infinite redirection

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site_one_folder/controller.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ site_one_folder/controller.php?para=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It is not working. Trying this is creating 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Stay only this lines in htacces and try again. I reproduce your folder structure. It works